# more than one selection arguments in SQLite for android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

how can I add more than one selection argument?

for example this is one argument selection

```
inputNumber  + "= ?"

new String[]{String.valueOf(numberToCheck)}
```

full cursor code

```
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(INSPECTION_PLAN_TRANSACTION,
 projection, inputNumber  + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(numberToCheck)},
 null, null, null, null);
```

how can i add another condition to the sql statement? like for example

```
input_number = numberToCheck AND name = "XXX"
```

input_number is an integer column and name is a column of Strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sqLiteDatabase.query(INSPECTION_PLAN_TRANSACTION,
 projection, input_number  + "= ? AND "+ name"= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(numberToCheck), "XXX"},
 null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(INSPECTION_PLAN_TRANSACTION,
 projection, inputNumber  + "= ? AND "+name+ " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(numberToCheck,nametocheck)},
```

Answer (score 0):

databse.query(String dbName, String[] columnNames, String whereClause, String[] selectionArgs, String[] groupBy, String[] having, String[] orderBy)

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME , 
                    new String[] {NAME_OF_COLUMNS_WHICH_IS_TO_BE_SELECT} ,
                    input number + "='" + numberToCheck + "' AND " +
                            name  + "='XXX'", 
                            null, null, null, null);
```